# bash scripting - how to use results from a function that is called as a variable

Tags: bash, unix

Trying to figure out how to pass results of one function to another (as a variable). Below is the script I am working on:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

set -x
_creds=/path/access
_pgpw=$(getPW)

getPW(){ 
  masterpw=$(grep -E 'url.*myfooapp.com' -A4 ${_creds}/access.json \
  | grep "pwd" \
  | awk '{split($0,a,":"); print a[2]}' \
  | grep -o '".*"' \
  | tr -d '"')
}

runQuery(){
  PGPASSWORD="${_pgpw}" \
  psql -h myfooapp.com -U masteruser -d dev -p 5439 
  echo "CLUSTER: ${_cluster}"
}

runQuery
set -x
```

What I need is `PGPASSWORD` to get the results from function `getPW` and its returning empty.  I'm not sure if I did this correctly with the variable `_pgpw=$(getPW)` with trying to call a function. Please advise on best way to accomplish this. Thanks

Comment: `getPW` creates a global variable named `masterpw`; it doesn't emit any stdout at all. However, `_pgpw=$(getPW)` is assigning the empty stdout of `getPW` to `_pgpw`.. so you're ending up with a populated variable named `masterpw`, and an empty variable named `_pgpw`. Or, rather, that's what you *would* be ending up with if you put the function definition above the invocation.

Comment: If you want the output of `getPW` to be assigned to `_pgpw`, then take out the `masterpw=$(` from the front of the function definition's body, and the `)` from the end, to stop redirecting that content into a FIFO used to assign `masterpw`, and thus away from the stdout content available for the command substitution used to assign `_pgpw`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thank you for your input and breaking that down for me.  Very informative. It works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash executes a script line by line as it reads it.  You need to define the function first, then call it.  As your script is written, `getPW` is called before it is defined so it is not producing any output.  Just move the `_pgpw=$(getPW)` line below the `getPW()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can take arguments; they are accessed inside the function via the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
runQuery () {
    PGPASSWORD=$1
    psql ...
}

runQuery "$(getPW)"
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I ran exactly as you showed with `$1`. I am still getting prompted for password as its still showing empty. From the debug I can see `masterpw` is being extracted, but just not populated for `PGPASSWORD`. `++ masterpw='123456!@#'
+ runQuery ''
+ PGPASSWORD=`

Comment: `psql` doesn't have support an environment variable analogous to `PGUSER` et al. for the password. You need to use a `.pgpass` file to store the password, or use a connection string instead of individual options; see e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-connect.html for more details.